# Autoit change name on window and use it in WinActivate

Tags: autoit

I have a function that starts some files and then change their names to their ids:

```
    Global $PID2 = Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar"', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Hub", $Hide)
    WinWaitActive("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe","",$PID2)
    Global $PID3 =Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar"', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Survival", $Hide)
    WinWaitActive("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe","",$PID3)
    Global $PID4 =Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar"', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\KnarWorld", $Hide)
    WinWaitActive("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe","",$PID4)
    Global $PID5 =Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar"', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Plotworld", $Hide)
    WinWaitActive("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe","",$PID5)
    Global $PID1 =Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "BungeeCord.jar"', 'E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\bungee', $Hide)
    WinWaitActive("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe","",$PID1)
```

I also have a function to stop the files:

```
WinActivate($PID1)
Send("end {ENTER}")
WinActivate($PID2)
Send("stop{ENTER}")
WinActivate($PID3)
Send("stop{ENTER}")
WinActivate($PID4)
Send("stop{ENTER}")
WinActivate($PID5)
Send("stop{ENTER}")
```

The problem is on the second function that instead of finding the ids and sending the wanted commands one by one, it starts spamming in whatever window is active. How can I make it run once and stop, but still work if I trigger it again?
The whole code: http://pastebin.com/U8XBk4HE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of tasks there are two functions:

- `SendKeepActive(...)` to make AutoIt to *attempt to reset the active window in between each simulated keystroke from Send()*.
- `ControlSend(...)` to send keystrokes to a specific window independently of it being active.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put a `WinWaitActive` to make it wait:

```
WinActivate($PID1)
WinWaitActive($PID1)
Send("end {ENTER}")
```